# Clean Windows 7 sysprep fails

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

I installed a new laptop, fresh clean Windows 7 Pro 64bit, when completed all installation i tried running sysprep but got this message:
"There was an error while trying to initialize the sysprep log."

laptop is in a domain, i'm logged in as domain admin and ran the sysprep as Administrator.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you verify that the domain admin is a local administrator on the laptop? What happens when you login as the local admin and run the sysprep as admin?

Comment: logged in as local admin, the sysprep started, but got another error saying "Fatal error occurred while trying to sysprep the machine". After a reboot, all local users were disabled and the machine seems to be out of the domain.

Comment: And have you checked the setuperr.log for the error? Also, what switches are you using when you run sysprep?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a domain account to run Sysprep. According to the [System Preparation (Sysprep) Technical Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825209.aspx):

> The Sysprep tool runs only if the PC is a member of a workgroup, not a
>   domain. If the PC is joined to a domain, Sysprep removes the PC from
>   the domain.

Please use the local administrator account instead to avoid this problem, and do not join the PC to the domain before trying to capture your image.

Hope this helps,